# Highcharts opacity of series color in line chart not active

Tags: highcharts, opacity

The color of the series has a reduced opacity:

```
      series: [{
      color: '#8ebfd7',
      opacity: .3,
      states: {
            hover: {
                opacity: 1                                                       
            }
      }]
```

At first the line should be transparent and on hover it should be dark. But it is dark at first and becomes transparent after the mouse once hovered over it. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/xaftyvr7/)

Answer (score 1):

I found that it is a documentation bug - this option should be applied like this. More information from the core developers you can find here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12092 and https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11750

This option should work only for particular states, so as a solution you can set each series state as inactive in the **chart.events.load**.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/076oL9xc/

```
events: {
  load() {
    let chart = this;
    chart.series.forEach(s => {
      s.setState('inactive')
    })
  }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load